# What is the first modern maths text?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, euclidean-geometry, math-history

I am aware that this question might appear subjective to some, but inasmuch as there is a definite difference between the algorithmic/algebraic type of mathematics practised by Euler (just like there is a definite difference between *that* mathematics and the Euclidean geometrical tradition), it appears reasonable to suppose that this shift was caused by some major work(s) which spread through to the rest of mathematics.

My questions are:

1. What was this particular work (or works) which started the modern abstract style of mathematics?
2. Is the difference in style to be attributed to the new branches of mathematics themselves, or is it more a difference of method (modus operandi)? In other words, is it possible to treat say Euclidean geometry qua Euclidean geometry but using the modern style, or is the ancient geometrical method somehow embedded/inseparable from Euclidean geometry?

Comment: For a "modern approach" to Euclidean geometry, see David Hilbert, [Grundlagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms#Editions_and_translations_of_Grundlagen_der_Geometrie) (original 1899) with previous works by [Moritz Pasch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moritz_Pasch) and [Mario Pieri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Pieri).

Comment: A forerunner of the "modern approach" can be found in the *Ausdehnungslehre* (1844) of [Hermann Grassmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Grassmann).

Comment: See also the [Erlangen program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program) (1872) by [Felix Klein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Klein).

Comment: I suppose that the criterion "abstract style" leads us to Bolyai and Lobachevsky: The "invention" of non-Euclidean geometry possibly coincides with detaching geometry as mathematical subject from the concrete geometry of the Universe

Comment: "there is a definite difference between the algorithmic/algebraic type of mathematics practised by Euler" AND WHAT? You have to have two things to have a "difference between". (With certain exceptions, e.g., "the difference between a duck".) Looks like an editing error.

Comment: For the benefit of those of us who *haven't* read Euler's textbook, could you kindly give some examples of what he did differently from the modern textbooks?

Comment: Tangential note: I sense that the question is predicated on "mathematics" being an eternal Platonic structure (e.g., "is it possible to treat say Euclidean geometry qua Euclidean geometry but using the modern style"). To the contrary, I'm coming to appreciate (via the interests of my colleague John Little) that in different cultures (such as Euclid's), there are substantial philosophical underpinnings difficult to separate from the ways definitions and theorems are organized and proofs structured.

Comment: Modern cars are different from those built in 1900. Which model caused this shift? History doesn't work this way.

Comment: @bof: Sorry for the late reply, I don't use SE often. There is actually not much of a difference between Euler and modern maths, if by modern maths we are only considering precalculus and computational calculus. These were basically derived in their modern form directly from the works of Euler, and the evidence is that our modern notation matches his too closely to be a mere coincidence, as the historians agree. Therefore, I see no reason why Euler cannot be used by a bright high school student to learn precalculus and calculus. In fact, this is precisely what Andre Weil recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about first, but I'd venture to say *Moderne Algebra* by van der Waerden, because of its impact.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderne_Algebra) says this about it:

> The book was one of the first textbooks to use an abstract axiomatic approach to groups, rings, and fields, and was by far the most successful, becoming the standard reference for graduate algebra for several decades. It "had a tremendous impact, and is widely considered to be the major text on algebra in the twentieth century"

Also, [A Course of Pure Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Course_of_Pure_Mathematics) by Hardy.

Comment: Would you recommend to read this book? How close it's to the nowadays formalism.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thanks man! Bought "A Course of Pure Mathematics: Third Edition by G. H. Hardy"